# Jest configuration for atom debugger xatom-debug-nodejs

Tags: node.js, debugging, atom-editor

I tried a lot but couldn't figure out the proper settings for running jest with my debugger.

Here's what I need to fill in:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you need to configure the path where the example node binary is located:
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Comment: Node is configured. I need to run jest though